# make appending strange folder to my makeprg on Windows

Tags: neovim, microsoft-windows, makeprg

I recently came to use NeoVim and I was trying to configure my vim to run a single file using `:make` command (My g++ is from MinGW), I tried to use

```
:let &makeprg = 'g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 -o %< %'
```

and ran `:make`, but it gives something like this:
[image: error message]

Why is there a weird folder `Temp\nvimHOQLoX`. How should I make my `:make` to compile my c++ file? I tried to use `:verbose make` and it gives this
[image: error message2]
I am able to run `make filename` in my Powershell but not in Neovim. Neovim is also using the Windows Powershell. `!make %<` works find too but I'd like to know why the previous command doesn't work. Thanks in advance!
I figured out the reason thanks to @filbrandon. Thank you!

Comment: In fact, this is strange. Have you tried to look into the `Temp\nvimHOQLoX` (perhapse it's the place where the quickfix lists are created)? If the folder doesent exist you can try to create it.

Comment: @Fabrice Yes, this folder is created but it is empty.

Comment: [Please don’t post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Comment: What does `:verbose set shellpipe?` tell you? Please [edit] your question to include the result. And please post that as text, so we can actually read it. Thanks!

Comment: @filbranden I reset it to windows default and it works, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you had the [`'shellpipe'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27shellpipe%27) option misconfigured to just a `|` instead of a `| tee` (which would work on Linux/Unix/WSL) or `>` (which would work on Windows.)

You can find the value this option is set to and the origin of this setting with:

```
:verbose set shellpipe?
```

As discussed in the comments, resetting this option to the Windows default worked to fix that for you.

Comment: Yes, it's indeed the case. That's what I saw from `:help shell-powershell` and it wrote that the command should be `shellpipe = \|` Any reason for it?

Comment: Yes it looks like the NeoVim docs do say that (https://neovim.io/doc/user/options.html#shell-powershell). This is a NeoVim addition, it's not in Vim. I can't tell why that's the advice... I don't rule out that being a mistake, with the author of the documentation change thinking that `'shellpipe'` is what the shell does for just a "pipe", when in fact that's more of a redirect...

Comment: I filed an issue in NeoVim about this: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/13713. Feel free to subscribe to it, to see how it gets resolved.